# Blazor read/write cookies using IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, httpcookie

So I have some problems using the IJSRuntime invoker to write and read cookies in Blazor using JavaScript. After some research, I found a guide to use the `IHttpContextAccessor` to read and write cookies using the `HttpContext`: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/

This is my current setup:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
    ...
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

**Index.razor**

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@code {
    private CookieController m_CookieController;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync () {
        m_CookieController = new CookieController(HttpContextAccessor); // Set HttpContextAccessor for setting and getting cookies
    }
}
```

**CookieController**

```
public class CookieController {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor m_HttpContextAccessor;
    
    public CookieController (IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        m_HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void SetCookie (String cookieName, String value, Int32? expireTime) {
        CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieName)) {
            return;
        }
        if (expireTime.HasValue) {
            option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireTime.Value);
        } else {
            option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        }
        if (m_HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response != null) {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
                value = "null";
            }
            m_HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(cookieName, value, option);
            return;
        }
    }

    public String ReadCookie (String cookieName) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieName)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (m_HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName])) {
            return m_HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So my problem here is that whenever I call `m_CookieController.SetCookie()`, I get the following exception:

> `System.InvalidOperationException: "The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started."`

What is wrong here, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Please don't post code or errors as pictures. It needs to be searchable.

Comment: Blazor cannot write cookies.   There is only 1 HTTP request when you start an app. From then on it is not HTTP based.

Comment: So any idea how I could possibly do this in .NET 5 without JSInvoke?

Comment: If that is not possible, I think I will write cookies using JS, and read them using the `IHttpContextAccessor `

Comment: That won't work with  Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** Use Blazor Server and finish setting cookies before the first http response is sent, as in the example below:

```
protected override void OnInitialized () {
    m_CookieController = new CookieController(HttpContextAccessor); // Set HttpContextAccessor for setting and getting cookies

    m_CookieController.SetCookie("Works","123");
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
    m_CookieController.SetCookie("Fails","456");
}
```

**More info:** Your code works as-is for me (thanks!) using Blazor Server, so I assume that you are either using Blazor WebAssembly, or that you are attempting to set cookies after the response was sent (which is likely the case if you replaced a `JS.InvokeAsync` line of code with your `SetCookie` function).

The Blazor Server [Component Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#component-initialization-oninitializedasync) isn't crystal clear regarding when the first http response is sent, but suffice to say that `OnInitialized` worked for me. `OnInitializedAsync` also worked for me, but note that it runs twice; the second run occurring "*when the browser renders the component*" (i.e., after the first http response is sent), so use `HttpContext.Response.HasStarted` to avoid the error you've reported.

Finally, as many comments have noted, this doesn't jive well with Blazor because `OnInitialized` won't be called again during normal use. However, you can force a page refresh with `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("any-page", true)`, which will let you set the cookies again.